# How to stop Google Sheets from increasing numbers when dragging a cell?

Tags: google-sheets

So I have a column with text like `abcd81`. If I drag the cell by that bottom right point then the next row will have `abcd82` and so on.

How can I prevent this behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copy the one cell you want duplicate.

Mark all the cells you want to have this value and paste

That worked for me

Answer (score 4):

On Windows, hold Ctrl button while dragging the cell. This will autofill the cell as-is.

Answer (score 2):

Use copy and paste instead of dragging the corner of the cell.

Answer (score 1):

On Mac, you can hold the Option key and drag the handle at corner of the originating cell.